# Add space above one of sidebar menu item

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to add space above one of sidebar menu item. For example 'Widgets' in the example below should be shown at the bottom of the page under sidebar (mean there should be space on top of the menu). I tried doing this with `tags$div(style = "margin-top: 50px;",` but didn't get desired output.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              )
      ),
      
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this CSS:

```
css <- "
.sidebar-menu li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
"

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(css))
    ),
    tabItems(
    ......
```